# Will the code be leaking

Tags: 2007, development, dispose

I've wrote here a code for SharePoint 2007 to modify few items through out of all site collections in web app, my question is the code written good, or is there a leak somewhere, and i could improve my code?

```
SPSiteCollection siteCollection = webApp.Sites;
foreach (SPSite site in siteCollection)
{
    SPWebCollection webCollection = site.AllWebs;
    foreach (SPWeb web in webCollection)
    {
        SPFeature feature = web.Features[new Guid(strGuid)];

        if (feature == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        SPListCollection listCollection = web.Lists;
        foreach (SPList list in listCollection)
        {
            if (!(list is SPDocumentLibrary))
            {
                continue;
            }
            SPListItem item = list.GetItemById("someid");
            item[strFieldName]="new value";
            item.SystemUpdate(false);
        }     
    }
}
```

So can anyone comment if my code is leak safe?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No your code isn't leak safe. It'll leak all of the SPSites and SPWebs

You need to add a dispose of each SPWeb and SPSite like this:

```
SPSiteCollection siteCollection = webApp.Sites;
foreach (SPSite site in siteCollection)
{
    SPWebCollection webCollection = site.AllWebs;
    foreach (SPWeb web in webCollection)
    {
        SPFeature feature = web.Features[new Guid(strGuid)];

        if (feature == null)
        {
            web.Dispose(); // Added
            continue;
        }

        SPListCollection listCollection = web.Lists;
        foreach (SPList list in listCollection)
        {
            if (!(list is SPDocumentLibrary))
            {
                continue;
            }
            SPListItem item = list.GetItemById("someid");
            item[strFieldName]="new value";
            item.SystemUpdate(false);
        }     
        web.Dispose(); // Added
    }
    site.Dispose(); // Added
}
```

or by using Using like this:

```
SPSiteCollection siteCollection = webApp.Sites;
foreach (SPSite site in siteCollection)
using (site) // Added
{
    SPWebCollection webCollection = site.AllWebs;
    foreach (SPWeb web in webCollection)
    using (web) // Added
    {
        SPFeature feature = web.Features[new Guid(strGuid)];

        if (feature == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        SPListCollection listCollection = web.Lists;
        foreach (SPList list in listCollection)
        {
            if (!(list is SPDocumentLibrary))
            {
                continue;
            }
            SPListItem item = list.GetItemById("someid");
            item[strFieldName]="new value";
            item.SystemUpdate(false);
        }     
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way of getting all the SPWebs with a feature enabled in SP2007. When you upgrade to SP2010/SP2013 you'll get the `SPWebApplication.QueryFeatures` method to help you.

But depending on what you're doing my guess would be that the handling of lists could be improved. Don't you know the URL of the list? Currently you're looping through them all and what happens if the users has added their own Document Libraries?

Comment: can i somehow implement it with using instead of site.dipose() or try ... catch

Comment: See updated answer for how to use `using`